# JWT Authentication with cookies NestJS (App Router)

Tags: authentication, cookies, next.js

In the project, we have NestJS backend and NextJS frameworks for the frontend part.
Backend logic:

1. set `auth-cookie` as `httpOnly` cookies after the authentication request.
2. check for the `auth-cookie` for a Guarded request.

The backend part works fine and has been tested using Postman (`localhost:4000`). We implemented endpoints to be able to call locally on the same port as NextJS with the help of proxy server logic there (`localhost:3000/api` for backend calls).

For example, now we can make auth `POST` on `http://localhost:3000/api/login` to the same NextJS server instead of accessing the backend server from the client app. We expect cookies to be set right after NextJS server will receive response from `POST localhost:4000/auth/login`. So that a client is not related to the backend directly.

**How to store these cookies on client side or reuse them for future?**

### src\app\api\login\route.ts

```js
import { _POST } from "@/providers/POST";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  return _POST(request, "/auth/login");
}
```

This is the route for `:3000/api/login` with `email` + `password` credentials.

### src\providers\POST.ts

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const _POST = async (request: NextRequest, url: string) => {
    /* 
        some configs 
    */
    
    let config = {
      method: "post",
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: backendURL + url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
     },
      data: data,
    };
    return axios
      .request(config)
      .then((response) => {
        const cookieStore = cookies();
        const tokenCookie = cookieStore.get("auth-cookie");
        console.log("tokenCookie", tokenCookie); // tokenCookie undefined
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data)); // successful authorization
        return NextResponse.json(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are setting the Set-Cookie response header but this may be due to the `Path` attribute not being configured.

Have you tried this?

It would look something like this after a successful login on the server:

```
return new Response('Success', {
 status: 200,
 headers: {
  'Set-Cookie': `token=${YOUR_TOKEN}; HttpOnly; Path=/`,
 },
})
```

Hope this helps.